# Why is my text all highlighted in orange in the Visual Studio for Mac text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

This has happened to me a few times now and it's driving me a special bit crazy.

For some reason Visual Studio for Mac decides to highlight sections of text in orange and once it happens no matter what I do this section will be orange. It gets hard to read when there is a lot of text in orange and now my eyes hurt.

I've been through all the settings for the text editor and can't find anything related?

[image: Image of text editor with sections highlighted in orange]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel so stupid. It turns out it was the Find feature. I had searched for 'Hall' and must of then started editing from the found section of 'Halloween'.

VS for Mac highlights search results in orange. If you then edit this orange section in just the right way it may turn a lot of text to be highlighted in orange.

To remedy, simply close the search dialog, or run another search over the text.

Comment: Thank: the same happened to me; I was trying to fix indentation and https://codesource.io/how-to-fix-vscode-indentation/ said the answer was to "Shift Option F" but I did Shift Command F which turned everything orange.

Comment: OK, at least I'm not the only one that was wondering why this happened all of a sudden.  I'm so used to using the Ctl+Shft+F seach I didn't even notice I had the quick search open.  Thank you...lol